# Где можно скачать(или получить например api) список всех улиц заданного города?

Tags: php, api

Для работы приложения нужно найти возможность скачать (или получить например api) список всех дорог заданного города ни гоогл ни яндекс такой возможности не дают, какой ресурс использовать для этого ?

Comment: Федеральная информационная адресная система (если вы из России конечно)

Answer (score 2):

Вообще не плохо было бы уточнить какая локация интересует! 
Есть много вариантов:

1. можно списки готовые попробовать найти - например [WiKi](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8)
2. список стран и городов можно через api например VK - [Database VK](https://vk.com/dev/database)
3. список улиц - [city-address.ru](https://city-address.ru)
4. Можно тупо с чужого сайта скоприровать
   и тд и тп...

Comment: Вы свои ссылки открывали? Как по первой ссылке найти улицы, например, Санкт-Петербурга? А по второй, где там улицы? В общем, ответ ни о чем, к сожалению.

Comment: да, открывал! а вы оказывается не только поиском не умеете пользоваться, но и банально ссылку открыть - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82:%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0

Comment: Ок, с Петербургом я погорячился, хотя с первой ссылки прямой ссылки на эту таки нет. Но как насчёт списка улиц хотя бы третьего по величине города России?

Comment: может мне за вас базу составить? я не против, много не возьму ))
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B_%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: https://city-address.ru/
короче как всегда, никто пальцем пошевелить не хочет, хотят сразу и в полном объеме, пытаешься помочь людям, но не благодарное это дело ) хорошего дня!

Comment: О, добавьте эту ссылку в свой ответ, вместо Википедии, она намного полезнее. А если ещё добавите ссылки на ФИАС или, для любителей извращений, КЛАДР, будет совсем хорошо. :)